# Extracting a Mathematica approximation of a curve from an image

Tags: image-processing

Suppose I have an image like the following:

[image]

and suppose Mathematica knows the correct scale of the image. Is there a way I could get Mathematica to approximate this with, say, a Bezier curve? Similarly if I drew a red point on here, could Mathematica extract the coordinates of the point?

Comment: Are you willing to extract points along the line manually or must this be done by code?

Comment: Ideally Mathematica would do this. I really only need loops in the same homotopy class, so I could draw some other loop manually and just parameterise that loop to get points. However, I already have several pictures like the above with loops already drawn so if I could extract points automatically, it might be a time saver.

Comment: If manually ok, you can show Drawing Tools in Mathematica. And then use the Get Coordinates Tool. Also see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you could identify pixels with different colors and extract the points.

Try `bild="copy of the image"` (sorry don't know how to show this code in simple form)

detect the dominant colors

```
dc = @DominantColors[bild]
```

get the points

```
points = Map[ PixelValuePositions[bild, #, .1 (*Colordistance*)] &, dc ]
```

#3 is the right one

```
ListPlot[point[[3]]]
```

[image]

`points[[3]]` might be taken to get   beziercurve-approximation